# Ingesting word documents into internal systems

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, outlook, vba

Current Problem: We have a vendor that provides us with a bill of lading in the form of a word document via email, and we are looking to ingest this information into our SQL Server database. I've done some of this in the past, but it was on more of an ad-hoc basis.

Previously, I created a VBA script in Excel to look at a list of file paths, open each document up, look for a starting range and ending range and copy/paste everything in between and move onto the next file.

This process is something we do on a daily basis, so I was wondering the capabilities of creating a dedicated email address (easy enough), but pulling out the attachment, and ultimately scraping it and ingesting the necessary information into a SQL server table?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you can code VBA then Python shouldn't be too much of a challenge (plus, it looks good on your CV ;-)

Have a read of:

- [How to extract data from MS Word Documents using Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ms-word-documents-using-python-ed3fbb48c122)
- [Working with PDF and Word Documents](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/)  from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python
- [pywordform - a Python module to parse MS Word forms (docx) to extract field values and tags](https://www.decalage.info/en/python/pywordform)
- [Parsing Word Documents](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2cm6ds/parsing_word_documents/) on Reddit
- [Use Python to parse Microsoft Word documents using PyWin32 Library](http://new.galalaly.me/2011/09/use-python-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-using-pywin32-library/)

Also, consider exporting from Word to another format, which might be easier to parse.

Please come back & let us know what you decide, as I might want to do this one day :-)